# Rendering Image in python to display in html

Tags: python, html, image

I am using this block of code to send an image from python to display in HTML.

```
x = cv2.imread(file)
x = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
img = io.BytesIO()
x = Image.fromarray(x, 'RGB')
x.save(img, 'PNG')
img.seek(0)
array.append(base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()))
k= k+1
id.append(k)

render_template('html_page.html', data=zip(array,id))
```

Code to display in HTML page:

```
{%for i,j in data%}
          <img for="id{{i}}" style = "float:left; width: 180px;" src="data:image/PNG;base64,{{ i }}" alt="display_Image">
{% endfor %}
```

The image is not getting displayed in the browser.

Can anyone point put what I am doing wrong? Trying to learn image processing with Python.

While debugging I am able to see that the image is getting loaded successfully in python function but is not getting displayed in HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because `base64` gives `bytes` and later template adds prefix `b` when it converts `bytes` to `string`. You have to manually `decode()` `bytes` to `string`.

```
base64.b64encode(img_io.getvalue()).decode()
```

---

**BTW:** If you have PNG files then you can do the same without `cv2`, `PIL` and `io`

```
data = open('image.png', 'rb').read()
image = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
```